Isomorphism-invariance and categorical properties in Set
I was studying category theory when a question came to my mind.
After this question, in which the topic appeared to be too broad, I'd like it to restrict the scope to the example of my current interest, namely Set. To be clearer, let me recall the necessary definitions.

Two sets are isomorphic if they are isomorphic in Set, i.e. if there exists an invertible map from one to the other.
A categorical property of a set is a property which can be expressible by means of the categorical language, namely using sets, maps, domain, codomain, composition and identity maps. For instance, being a terminal set is a categorical property of the set.

It has been pointed out in the aforementioned question that two isomorphic sets have the same categorical properties, provable by induction of the length of a formula in the categorical language (once defined it precisely).
I'm wondering about the vice versa. Is it true that two sets having the same categorical properties are isomorphic? To prove that, it would be sufficient to prove that, for every set X, the property "being isomorphic to X" is a categorical property.

Yes if you allow the language of colimits (or at least coproducts) with arbitrary index sets. Every set $X$ is a coproduct of copies of the terminal set indexed by the set $X$.
This can be used to show that the automorphism class group of $\mathbf{Set}$ is trivial.
A set has $<\kappa$ elements precisely when it is $\kappa$-presentable, at least when $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal. This gives another characterization of "the" set of cardinality $\kappa$. The definition of a presentable object involves $\kappa$-filtered colimits.
If you don't allow colimits (or something similar, such as ordinal-indexed sequences of morphisms), only the finitary language made up out of $\circ$, $\mathrm{cod}$ etc. then I think it's not possible (EDIT: see David's answer).
We can characterize finite sets $X$ categorically by the property that every epimorphism $X \to X$ is an isomorphism. More precisely, we can recursively characterize sets which have cardinality $n$ for $n < \aleph_0$. The case $n=0$ corresponds to an initial object. A set has $n$ elements when it admits an irreducible* monomorphism from a set with $n-1$ elements.
But infinite sets are the issue here. We can characterize $\aleph_0$ up to isomorphism as an infinite set which admits a monomorphism to any other infinite set. If we have characterized $\aleph_{\alpha}$, a similar idea to the finite case yields a characterization of $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$. If $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal, and we have already characterized $\aleph_\alpha$ for all $\alpha < \lambda$, it seems tempting to also write down a characterization of $\aleph_\lambda$, but this doesn't work in the finitary language above since we would need to combine infinitely many formulas into one. So while we can characterize $\aleph_0,\aleph_1,\dotsc$ we probably cannot characterize $\aleph_\omega$, as David writes.
*Here I call a monomorphism irreducible when it is not an isomorphism and in every factorization into two morphisms one of these is an isomorphism.

PS. Maybe you are interested in this MO discussion about categorical properties: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55931

Are your “categorical properties” allowed to contain parameters (i.e. with free variables), or are you just considering closed properties (i.e. with no free variables)?  If you just mean closed properties, then David Gao’s answer nicely shows that the answer is no, since there are just countably many closed properties, but proper-class-many isomorphism classes of sets.  If you allow parameters, then the answer is near-trivially yes, since then “…is isomorphic to $X$” is a categorical property which (as you note in the question) distinguishes $X$ from any set not isomorphic to it.
What I want to argue is that you should be considering properties-with-parameters — not only does the fact “isomorphic sets have the same categorical properties” hold for these too, but indeed any proof of that fact for closed properties goes via proving it for properties-with-parameters.  At least, all reasonably natural approaches I can think of go by syntactic induction on formulas; but closed formulas are typically build by quantification of formulas with free variables.  So if you try to prove the invariance for just closed properties, you find you have to first generalise your claim to include properties with parameters as well.  Once they’re included, the theorem is a straightforward induction.
This is very typical, since unlike possibly-open formulas, closed formulas are not a self-contained class admitting an induction principle.  Both notions are important and of interest — some theorems genuinely hold just for closed formulas — but the proofs of such theorems usually involve first generalising them to some more involved statement covering possibly-open formulas as well, which generally argues for properties-with-parameters as the primary notion of properties expressible in a given language, whenever there isn’t a specific reason to restrict to closed formulas.
Another example is how axiom schemes ranging over all formulas/properties, such as PA’s induction or ZF’s separation and replacement, almost always allow parameters in the formulas/properties they range over: PA’s induction is not just induction for closed properties, “$(\varphi(0) \wedge \forall x\ (\varphi(x) \to \varphi(Sx))) \to \forall x\, \varphi(x)$”, but for properties with parameters: “$\newcommand{\y}{\vec{y}}\forall \y \left((\varphi(\y,0) \wedge \forall x\ (\varphi(\y, x) \to \varphi(\y,Sx))) \to \forall x\, \varphi(\y,x)\right)$”.  This is essential when working inside these theories as foundations, but also often important for working with their models/interpretations, again essentially since open formulas form a natural inductive system while closed formulas do not.

Here is a formal proof of impossibility to express “being isomorphic to $X$” in the first order language of categories for a general $X$, as already suggested in Martin’s answer: There are only countably many formulae in the first-order language of categories, so even if allowing for sets of formulae to define an isomorphism class, there are at most continuum many isomorphism classes that can be defined. But there are, of course, a proper class of cardinals. This also shows having the same categorical properties, if “categorical properties” are interpreted as properties expressible in the first order language of categories, is not enough to guarantee two sets are isomorphic.
It is perhaps a more interesting question to ask which cardinals can actually be defined. It’s not hard to see every cardinal smaller than $\aleph_\omega$ can be defined this way, but it is not immediate obvious to me whether any other cardinal is definable.
